# Is that possible to count toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im curious , is that possible to count toggle ? Because I have one problem , when I hover it and hover out multiple times and select one of the item, the button will push to bottom and not able to seen. Or that is another way to fixed this problem ?

**updated**

Not multiple times even I hover in and hover out and hover it again it also push to bottom.

[click here for js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v07vt9gz/)

**JS**

```
        $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
        $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: "toggle"
        }, 500, function () {
            $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(orig); // Here put the original text.

        }).css('position', 'relative');

    }, function () {
        $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: "toggle"
        }, 500, function () {
            $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(newText); // Here put the new text with "..."

        }).css('position', 'relative');
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: not able to replicate the problem mentioned?

Comment: @Mritunjay what do you mean ??

Comment: Your question is unclear. What can't you see exactly? What button is pushed to the bottom? No such effect is seen in the fiddle provided by you.

Comment: @Aditya the button will show when selected an item. Did you try to select ??

Comment: Yeah tried that so you want the finish button to show up?

Comment: @Aditya yeah ~ did u try the problem ? hover in and out and hover again then select item

Comment: @Aditya did you have solution to fixed this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to fixed this problem .

```
      $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
    $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function () {
        $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(orig); // Here put the original text.

    }).css('position', 'relative');

}, function () {
    $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function () {
        $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(newText); // Here put the new text with "..."

    }).css('position', 'relative');
});
```

**change `$('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop()` to `$('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish()` for both animate**